# how do I get my controller data to my view so javascript can use it?

Tags: javascript, ajax, view

I'm new to laravel. I have a controller that should pass an array to the view.

```
public function php()
    {
        $NewGetGSResults = $this->GetGSResults();
        $dataRes = $NewGetGSResults = $this->GetGSResults();
        print_r($dataRes);
        $title = "Bitches";
        $dataArr = array($title, $dataRes);
        $dataArr =json_encode($dataArr);
        //print_r($dataArr);

        return $dataArr;
    }
```

$title is a string and $datRes is an array of strings

I can't get ajax to work.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/php",

            success: function(data) {
                var res = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("Ajax Broke!");
            }
        });
```

I would like to loop thru the data and apply it to some js code but I keep getting and error and don't know why.

error="SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: try to `console.log(data)` before `JSON.parse` and check your data

Comment: I reworked my ajax call and removed the JSON encoding so I am now passing an array. I don't know if this is the proper way of doing it (everyone says use JSON) but this worked for me.  I can loop thru the array and extract the specific elements I want.